# 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in laravel 5, foreign key

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, migration, database-migration

**2019_04_23_164151_create_contacts_table.php** migration file

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

 class CreateContactsTable extends Migration
 {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{

    Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('surname');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('contacts_relations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('phone_id')->nullable()->default(1);
        $table->unsignedInteger('contact_id')->nullable()->default(1);
    });

    Schema::create('contact_phone', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('phone_number');
        $table->unsignedInteger('contacts_relations_id')->nullable()->default(1);
    });

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('contacts');
}}
```

**2019_04_24_183110_contacts_relations.php** foreign key setter

```
 <?php

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

 class ContactsRelations extends Migration
 {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('contacts_relations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts');
    });
    Schema::table('contact_phone', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('contacts_relations_id')->references('id')->on('contacts_relations');
    });

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
}
}
```

run php artisan migrate: fresh and get 
**SQLSTATE [HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `contacts_relations` add constraint`contacts_relations_contact_id_foreign` foreign key (`contact_id`) references`contacts` (`id` ) on delete cascade on update cascade)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure all columns are eact same type. For example in table `contacts` the `id` column is unsigned big integer, so when you create `contact_id` column in `contacts_relations` instead of:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('phone_id')->nullable()->default(1);
```

it should be:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('phone_id')->nullable()->default(1);
```

Similar thing for `contacts_relations_id` column

Comment: Also since there is a default value remove nullable  $table->unsignedBigInteger('phone_id')->default(1);

Comment: @Rachid Well, default might by 1, but in some cases you might want to set to `null`